# How to git restore ONLY deleted files

Tags: bash, git

After running some bash commands, some files were accidentally deleted. Doing `git status` shows a *mix* of deleted and modified files, e.g.

```
        deleted:    folder/README.md
        modified:   folder/somescript.sh
```

If there is a long list of deleted files I don't want to manually `git restore` each individually, and a `git checkout .` would discard my yet to be stashed or committed changes. How do I restore **only the deleted files** leaving the modified files untouched?

Sharing my own quick hack in an answer, but better solutions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Combined the suggestions in the comments, to make a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

```bash
git config --global alias.restore-deleted '!git restore $(git ls-files -d)'
```

Now I can just run `git restore-deleted` to restore deleted files and leave the modified ones untouched.

### Original Version

This is what I put in my *~/.bashrc*:

```bash
alias restoredeleted="git status | grep deleted | sed -e 's/deleted://' | xargs git restore"
```

Then I can conveniently run `restoredeleted`.

Comment: You could even make this a git alias. `git restore-deleted`?

Comment: Don't use `git status` (a "porcelain" command) where a plumbing command will do: `git ls-files -d` finds deleted files. (Turning this into a fully bulletproof version is tricky, but `git restore $(git ls-files -d)` is simpler than what you have and less subject to porcelain issues. Expand it a bit to use xargs if you like; `xargs -0` works well with `git ls-files -dz`.)

Comment: @evolutionxbox great idea, didn't think of using a git alias. torek, that can be an answer, much better! Assumed you wanted me to update my answer, so did just that. Thanks to you both.